# Реализация Singleton для arm-gcc под stm32

Tags: c++, stm32

Пробую пощупать VisualGDB + CubeMX.
При инстанцировании такого вот синглтона:

```
class Singleton
{
    
public:
    
    static void update()
    {
        getInstance()._counter++;
    }
    
private:
    
    Singleton() {}
    Singleton(Singleton const &) = delete;
    void operator=(Singleton const &)  = delete;
    
    static Singleton& getInstance()
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }
    
    int _counter = 0;
};
```

в функции

```
extern "C"
void main_loop()
{
    Singleton::update();
}
```

которая потом вызывается из кода на С, генерируемого CubeMX, компилятор создает что-то отъедающее очень много памяти:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это исправить.

Comment: Возможно это связано с наличием статической переменной? Что будет если перенести `static Singleton instance;` в класс, убрать статик и создать синглтон локально?

Comment: Так работает, я уже пробовал. Но хотелось бы оставить классическую реализацию синглтона Мейрса.

Comment: А что если вынести статик в класс и там оставить? Возможно есть какие-то проблемы с локальными статическими переменными? Кстати я бы поправил синтаксис немного: обычно в синглтонах есть только 1 статическая функция `getInstance()`, в таком случае `update()` может быть обычной функцией, а его вызов будет выглядеть так `Singleton::getInstance().update();`

Comment: У меня уже есть достаточно большое количество кода в таком стиле (все функции класса - статические), и это без проблем работало под AVR. Думал, получится без особых проблем перенести...